# Multiplying elements in arrays using the forEach function

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, multiplication

I'm currently learning about arrays and the different ways to manipulate them. I was asked to: "multiply 5 to the given array using the forEach function"

Here is my code so far.

It looks as if everything works when I console.log in the forEach function, but when I log the console for the array it's read as undefined.

```js
let multiplyArray = [1, 11, 7, 3, 8, 2, 3, 2, 10, 3, 6, 2, 5];

function multiplyNumbers() {
  let numbers;
  multiplyArray.forEach(function(element) {
    let fiveTimesNum;
    fiveTimesNum = (element * 5);
    element = fiveTimesNum;
    console.log(element)
  });
  console.log('The array(element) value is read out correctly, but when I console log the array its value is ↓')
  return numbers
}
multiplyArray = (multiplyNumbers());
console.log(multiplyArray);
```

Comment: Assigning a value to `element` does not update the existing array.

Comment: You're returning `numbers` but you never added anything to that variable

Comment: element is just the value, it is not the reference to the item in the index. Now the big issue is you defined numbers and you never assign it anything. You then return it. You want to use `map()`

Comment: `const multiplyNumbers  = () => multiplyArray.map(v => v * 5);`

Comment: Is there a way to do it without (element) that will update the existing array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the array `multiplyArray` in place you can it like this:

```js
let multiplyArray = [1, 11, 7, 3, 8, 2, 3, 2, 10, 3, 6, 2, 5];

multiplyArray.forEach(function(n,i,a){a[i]=5*n;});

console.log(multiplyArray);
```

Comment: I am super new learning about arrays is there anyway you could write this same code out without using the shorthand method of => and use it as a function instead so I can understand what going on better?

Comment: Nothing easier than that :D ... ( `(n,i,a)=>...)` _is_ a function definition)

Answer (score 2):

From the task, it seems like you're supposed to update the given array. With a forEach loop you can reference the array you are looping on along with the index and value

```
let multiplyArray = [1, 11, 7, 3, 8, 2, 3, 2, 10, 3, 6, 2, 5];
multiplyArray.forEach(function(val, i, arr){
    arr[i] = val*5;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Numbers was never defined correctly, please see example below.

You can use your mapped array to return the correct data.

```js
let multiplyArray = [1, 11, 7, 3, 8, 2, 3, 2, 10, 3, 6, 2, 5];

function multiplyNumbers() {
  multiplyArray.forEach(function(element) {
    let fiveTimesNum;
    fiveTimesNum = (element * 5);
    element = fiveTimesNum;
    console.log(element)
  });
  console.log('The array(element) value is read out correctly, but when I console log the array its value is ↓')
  return multiplyArray
}
multiplyArray = (multiplyNumbers());
console.log(multiplyArray);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using the (element parameter) that will update the existing array without having to map?